# Why do I need "height: auto" for responsive images?

Tags: css

Is it necessary to define the `height: auto` now days? and what the reasons is?

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sure the image is always displayed in the original aspect ratio. It's a common technique to realize responsive display of images. The important part is actually to always set only **either** `width` **or** `height` to soemthin other than `auto`. The browser will then resize the image, maintaining the aspect ratio.

`max-width: 100%;` in your code example makes sure the image is never displayed wider than its parent container.

## In your code example, setting it is not necessary:

Most `<img>` have so-called intrinsic dimensions (such as JPG, PNG, GIF). In this case, stating **neither `width` nor `height` explicitly** makes the browser use those intrinsic dimension as a default for the given image. As soon as you specifiy exactly one of these, the other will be set to `auto`.

Comment: True of many [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element).

Answer (score 4):

On an image without a height dimension explicitly set anywhere, it will actually default to height auto. So if you set `max-width: 100%;` the height will automatically be calculated by the browser to be the correct aspect ratio.

You may then think that it is not necessary to set the height to auto in the css but the real reason for it is if a height has been set on the img element with the *height html attribute* like this:

```
<img src="#" height="500" />
```

Although you may not set the height attribute explicitly yourself I know that wordpress for instance does set the height attribute on images that are pulled from the media library.

In this case if you only have set max-width to 100% the image will not be wider than the containing element but the aspect ratio will be wrong, the image most likely will be stretched taller. Use the css height auto to override the img tag height attribute.

That is why Bootstraps `.img-responsive` class sets `height: auto;`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not.

[**MDN's docs on `height` states:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)

> Initial value: **auto**

So, height property will be `auto` by default.

Comment: While this is true for regular block-level elements, it's wrong for `img` that have so-called *intrinsic dimensions* (such as JPG, PNG, GIF). In this case, neither stating width nor height explicitly makes the browser use those intrinsic dimension as a default for the given image. As soon as you specifiy exactly **one** of these, the other will be set to `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

**auto** is the default value of the **height** CSS property. So, you don't need to define that value in the **img** element selector because you are not overriding it with a different value, you are just using the same default value.

Comment: Again, also for you, young padawan: While this is true for regular block-level elements, it's wrong for `<img>` that have so-called *intrinsic dimensions* (such as JPG, PNG, GIF). In this case, **neither stating width nor height** explicitly makes the browser use those intrinsic dimension as a default for the given image. As soon as you specifiy exactly *one* of these, the other will be set to `auto`.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you want/are trying to do.

```
height:100%;
```

The element is going to have the 100% height of its parent container.

```
height:auto;
```

The element will have a flexible height. The height will adjust according to the height of the children elements within it.

Comment: OP explicitly showed ìmg` example. `img` cannot have children.