# Is there any point to setting height to auto when a width is specified?

Tags: css

A freeCodeCamp [lesson](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/responsive-web-design-principles/make-an-image-responsive) requires you to include `height: auto` in the following snippet for the answer to be accepted:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

However, height is auto by default, so I don't see any reason this should be added.

I have seen this used in other people's code as well.

Is this just an oversight?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need "height: auto" for responsive images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631732/why-do-i-need-height-auto-for-responsive-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The default value of `height` is `auto` ([per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)), and for the scenario you're discussing (making an image responsive), you do not need to specify that property.

That said, when editing styles of an existing project, you may find yourself in a situation where you need to override already written CSS rules. That's where knowing about `height: auto` would come in handy - if you wanted to overrule a hardcoded height on an image and set it back to the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. Height: auto is default, regardless if you put a width or length. I doesn't really matter, unless you just want to write more code or something. It is also may be used because if for example if you have:

```
*{height:200px}
```

Then you would have to override the default. 200px;